# How to list the theorems, lemmas etc without sections? I would like 'Theorem 1', 'Lemma 2', 'Theorem 3' etc

Tags: sectioning, formatting, theorems, sections-paragraphs, lemma

I only have theorems and lemmas in my short document, and it does not make sense to have then listed with sections and subsections. I also have no corollaries (to be clear, this is a homework assignment so it is primarily 'question', 'proof', I only have to state a theorem and a lemma which I use in my proofs.)

Is there a way to have Theorem 1...... Lemma 2
i.e. keep the number ordering, no subsections?

EDIT:

I have added the requested example document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}




\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{claim}{Claim}

\title{Zero}
\author{The Hero}
\date{December 2171}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
...
\end{question}

\begin{proof}
...
\end{proof}

\begin{theorem}{Einstein's special theorem of relativity}
$E^2 = m^2c^4+p^2c^2$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{question}
...
\end{question}

\begin{proof}
...
\end{proof}

\begin{lemma}{Euclid's Lemma}
If a prime p divides the product ab of two integers a and b, then p must divide at least one of those integers a and b.
\end{lemma}

\begin{question}
...
\end{question}

\begin{proof}
...
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Notw that I realise I am using the second set of {} in the theorem and lemma environments incorrectly. It does not provide a title for the theorem in this way :?

Comment: Can you provide a *minimal* example that replicates your current setup? The code you present should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. It is important to know what package you use for your theorem creation. Can you do that?

Comment: @Werner I have done this now :)

Comment: If you want to let Theorem and Lemma share the same counter, change `\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}` to `\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}`.

Comment: Thanks @muzimuzhiZ ! For some reason I was convinced that that meant I wanted the lemma count to follow on from the preceding theorem as decimal, i.e. as if the theorem was a section. :X